# Using enum from C++ to python

Tags: python, c++, enums

How can I use enum in a C++ python wrapper ? I came across this topic:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/enum.html

But I would like to do the same without using the boost.

I found a workaround to do the same, but then I would like to improvise on it/  better way to do this:

In the init method I can add :

```
   PyObject* enum_1= Py_BuildValue("i", 1);
   PyModule_AddObject(my_module, "my_enum_1", enum_1);
```

Now I can treat my_enum_1 as a enum with the value 1 and use it in other methods in C++ wrapper, and the python script.

Wrapper method:

```
static PyObject *
   PyClass_checkEnum (PyClass *self,
   PyObject *args)
{
   int y = -1;
   if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"i", &y))
   {
      //Error
   }
   else
   {
      //use the enum
      int op = self->getPtr()->checkEnum(y);
      py_returned_tuple = Py_BuildValue("i", op);
   }

   return py_returned_tuple;
}
```

In the python script, I can directly call the mapped method

```
checkEnum(my_enum_1)
```

But then I do not know how to use them when I have saveral enums in different namespaces. So If I would like to call something like

```
checkEnum(namespace1.my_enum_1)
```

How am I going to achieve this ?

Comment: Why not just put the enum values in an int* array?

Comment: @Desolator How exactly do you suggest ? I am not sure how to do it with the namespace ?

Comment: I mean just use int arrays rather than enums